# Exclude Newstrading Days via input.bool

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading

that's my code:

```
FilterNewsTrading = input.bool(defval=false,title='Filter Newstrading')

no_trade_day_dec22 = (year == 2022) and (month == 12) and (dayofmonth == 13) or (dayofmonth == 14) or (dayofmonth == 2)// 13.12.2022 CPI // 14.12.2022 Interest Rate // 02.12.2022 NFP
no_trade_day_jan23 = (year == 2023) and (month == 01) and (dayofmonth == 12) or (dayofmonth == 06) // 12.01.23 CPI // 06.01.2023 NFP
no_trade_day_feb23 = (year == 2023) and (month == 02) and (dayofmonth == 01) or (dayofmonth == 03) // 01.02.23 Interest Rate // 03.02.2023 NFP
NewsExcluded = FilterNewsTrading ? not na(no_trade_day_dec22 and no_trade_day_jan23 and no_trade_day_feb23) : true

if (inDateRange and LongEntry and NewsExcluded)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, comment="entry long")
```

So the idea is to have an easy checkbox, where I can select, if the dates should be excluded or not to see, how my equity curve changes. Unfortunately it doesnt work. Does anyone know, where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking your "no trade day"s in a `na()` function. That function is just to test if soemthing is `na` or not.

What you should be doing is:

```
NewsExcluded = FilterNewsTrading ? (no_trade_day_dec22 or no_trade_day_jan23 or no_trade_day_feb23) : false

if (inDateRange and LongEntry and not NewsExcluded)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, comment="entry long")
```

I kinda reversed your logic.

Here, I `or`'d your no trade conditions `(no_trade_day_dec22 or no_trade_day_jan23 or no_trade_day_feb23)`. So, if the current bar is on any of those days, it will return `true`.

If the checkbox is not enabled, `NewsExcluded` will be `false` due to `: false` at the end.

Then in your if condition, I have changed it to `not NewsExcluded`.

If the checkbox is enabled and if it is one of those days, `NewsExcluded` will be `true` and the statement `not NewsExcluded` will be `false` preventing the `strategy.entry()` call.

If the checkbox is disabled, `NewsExcluded` will be `false` and the statement `not NewsExcluded` will be `true`. In that case, it is up to the other conditions (`inDateRange and LongEntry`).

Comment: ah damn - that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation vitruvius, that helped a lot and I also learned something. Will be helpful for the future!